# Visual Composer text don't fit in mobile

Tags: wordpress, mobile, plugins, visual-composer

Is there a way to expand a section height in Visual Composer plug in so text fits OK in mobile? 
Shrinking text is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Row stretch` however it may not work properly if parent container has `overflow: hidden` CSS property

Resources:
https://wpbakery.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/VC/pages/3604483/How+to+make+full+width+or+full+height+row
https://wpbakery.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/VC/pages/524364/Content+Elements